# Net Core, generate RouteLink with html as linkText parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to create an link with a svg icon and i need to use

```
RouteLink(this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string routeName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering`.

If I do the following:

```
var link = html.RouteLink("<svg class=\"icon\"><use href=\"#chevron-left\"></use></svg>", model.RouteActionName, model.RouteValues, new { title = "Previous page" });
```

Then for example I get

```
<a href="/heropoints/history/page/1" title="Previous Page">&lt;svg class="icon"&gt;&lt;use href="#chevron-left"&gt;&lt;/use&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;</a>
```

So the string `linkText` is not being rendered at html. Does anyone know how can I overcome this? So I get regular html as the linktext like this:

```
<svg class="icon"><use href="#chevron-left"></use></svg>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Html.Raw() method.

```
var link =Html.Raw(html.RouteLink("<svg class=\"icon\"><use href=\"#chevron-left\"></use></svg>", model.RouteActionName, model.RouteValues, new { title = "Previous page" }));
```

Edit:

```
var routelink =html.RouteLink("<svg class=\"icon\"><use href=\"#chevron-left\"></use></svg>", model.RouteActionName, model.RouteValues, new { title = "Previous page" });
var link = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(routelink.ToHtmlString());
```

Comment: No, that'll also print the `<a>` as `&lt;a&gt;`.

Comment: Hmm. So, can use this: System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(link) it work for me now. Try it.

Comment: i found an solution that worked for me and suggested an little edit to your anwer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the URL and render the HTML yourself:

```
<a href="@html.RouteUrl(Model.RouteActionName, model.RouteValues" title="Previous page">
    <svg class="icon">
        <use href="#chevron-left" />
    </svg>
</a>
```